# How can we select all rows from numpy ndarray by comparing value from column indexing 2 and consisting word 'Approved' in string

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

```
['1' 'Approved by person XYZ' 'date'] ['1' 'Approved by person ABC' 'date'] ['1' 'Approved by person PQR' 'date'] ['1' 'Approved by person STD' 'date']
```

this is my array and i want to select only those records which contain 'Approved'. I know this might be a silly question as i am using string values in ndarray but still want to know.

Comment: `import re indexes = [n for n,i in enumerate(a) for j in i if re.match(r'Approved', j)]` If you wanna get index of element

Answer (score 0):

```py
arr = [['1', 'Approved by person XYZ', 'date'], ['1', 'Approved by person ABC', 'date'], ['1', 'Approved by person PQR', 'date'], ['1', 'Approved by person STD', 'date']]

[record for record in arr if 'Approved' in record[1]]
```

Works for both np.arrays and nested lists. Returns a list of records